# Is the R before string cross-platform

Tags: c++, c++11, cross-platform

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn519920.aspx), this code is used in order to match regular expression:

```
if (regex_match(s, m, regex { R"((\w+) (\w+))" }))
{
}
```

Is using the R before the string quota a standard C++?

Comment: Raw string literals were introduced with the C++11 standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes; this notation is known as a "raw string literal", and was standardized in C++11. Further (non-MSDN) documentation can be found [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal).

Answer (score 3):

Yes it's standard C++. So as such is cross-platform. According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal):

```
prefix(optional) R "delimiter( raw_character* )delimiter"
```

Represents raw string literal. Used to avoid escaping of any character, anything between the delimiters becomes part of the string, if prefix is present has the same meaning as described above.